# pd dataframe addings rows by id

Tags: python, pandas

I have df with some ids, days number and running sum:

```
data = {'id': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1], 'day' : [0, 2, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2], 'running_sum': [1,4,2,1,6,6,3]}
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data)


    id  day running_sum
0   0   0   1
1   0   2   4
2   0   1   2
3   1   1   1
4   1   4   6
5   2   2   6
6   1   2   3
```

I wanna have dataframe of all days for each id with the correct running sum:

```
    id  day running_sum
0   0   0   1
1   0   1   2
2   0   2   4
3   0   3   4
4   0   4   4
5   1   0   0
6   1   1   1
7   1   2   3
8   1   3   3
9   1   4   6
10  2   0   0
11  2   1   0
12  2   2   6
13  2   3   6
14  2   4   6
```

thanks for the help

Comment: What is the relationship between the `day` and `running_sum`?

Comment: no relationship, just random data.
of course the running sum of the same id cant go down if the day go up.

Comment: Then how do you define _correct running sum_ for days? Only logic I see here is for all ids to have same range of minimum and maximum days (0 to 4) but I don't understand how the newly inserted days get the corresponding `running_sum`

Comment: for missings days I wanna get the last value of running_sum

Comment: @Chris, I think you should ignore the running prefix, I do not think there is anything cumulative about it

Answer (score 3):

Let's see if this logic is what you have in mind:

Set `id` and `day` as index:

```
df_1 = df_1.set_index(['id', 'day'])
```

Build a new index to reindex `df_1` while introducing new numbers; luckily the index is unique, so reindex works fine:

```
new_index = df_1.index.get_level_values('id').unique()

new_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([new_index, range(5)],
                                       names = ['id', 'day'])

df_1 = df_1.reindex(new_index)
```

Groupby `id` and filldown on each group, the rest nulls will be replaced with zero:

```
(df_1.assign(running_sum = df_1.groupby('id')
                               .running_sum
                               .ffill()
                               .fillna(0))
     .reset_index()
)

    id  day  running_sum
0    0    0          1.0
1    0    1          2.0
2    0    2          4.0
3    0    3          4.0
4    0    4          4.0
5    1    0          0.0
6    1    1          1.0
7    1    2          3.0
8    1    3          3.0
9    1    4          6.0
10   2    0          0.0
11   2    1          0.0
12   2    2          6.0
13   2    3          6.0
14   2    4          6.0
```

If you are not averse to using an add-on library, the [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.complete.html#janitor.complete) function/method from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) could help abstract the process:

```
# pip install pyjanitor
import pyjanitor
df = df_1.complete('id', {'day':range(5)}) # explicitly expose the missing values

df.assign(running_sum = df.groupby('id').running_sum.ffill().fillna(0))

    id  day  running_sum
0    0    0          1.0
1    0    1          2.0
2    0    2          4.0
3    0    3          4.0
4    0    4          4.0
5    1    0          0.0
6    1    1          1.0
7    1    2          3.0
8    1    3          3.0
9    1    4          6.0
10   2    0          0.0
11   2    1          0.0
12   2    2          6.0
13   2    3          6.0
14   2    4          6.0
```

All this is premised on the assumption that I got the logic right

Answer (score 0):

You can `unstack`/`stack` and `ffill`. The tricky part is to get the missing 'days':

```
missing = set(range(0, df_1['day'].max()+1)).difference(df_1['day'].unique())

(pd.concat([df_1,
            pd.DataFrame({'id': 0, 'day': list(missing)})])
   .set_index(['id', 'day'])
   .unstack()
   .stack(dropna=False)  ## adds the missing values
   .sort_index()
   .groupby('id')
   .ffill()
   .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
   .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
    id  day  running_sum
0    0    0            1
1    0    1            2
2    0    2            4
3    0    3            4
4    0    4            4
5    1    0            0
6    1    1            1
7    1    2            3
8    1    3            3
9    1    4            6
10   2    0            0
11   2    1            0
12   2    2            6
13   2    3            6
14   2    4            6
```